# How to add a select box with the same values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

I have code to add some select box, but I can't add the same value of select box. This is my HTML code

```
<input onClick="addRow('dataTable')" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary">  

        <input onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">

        <div style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">  
            <table id="dataTable" border="0">  
            <tbody>
            <tr>    
                <td width="40px"></td>
                <td align="center">Number</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
               <td><input name="chk" type="checkbox"></td>  
               <td>
                    <select id='kap' name='kap'>
                        <option value=''>-- number --</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="60">60</option>
                    </select>
                </td>  
            </tr>  
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

In this case I want to add some values equal to the selectbox id='kap'. This is my javascript code

```
function addRow(tableID) {  

 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);  
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;  
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);  

 var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);  
 var element1 = document.createElement("input");  
 element1.type = "checkbox";  
 element1.name="chkbox[]";  
 cell1.appendChild(element1);  

 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);  
 var element3 = document.createElement("select");  
 var element3 = document.getElementById("kap");
 element3.type = "select";
 element3.name = "selectbox[]"
 cell2.appendChild(element3);   

 }
```

Comment: Do you want to make a copy of the select element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var element3 = document.getElementById("kap").cloneNode(true);
```

Check it out here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfrtmeq2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);  
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;  
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);  

 var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);  
 var element1 = document.createElement("input");  
 element1.type = "checkbox";  
 element1.name="chkbox[]";  
 cell1.appendChild(element1);  

 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);  
 var element3 = document.createElement("select");  
 var elementCopy = document.getElementById("kap");
 element3.type = "select";
 element3.name = "selectbox[]";
 for(var i = 0; i < elementCopy.options.length; i++)
 {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = elementCopy.options[i].innerHTML;
    element3.appendChild(elementCopy);
 }
 cell2.appendChild(element3);
```

Something like this will loop through the options in the first select and add them to the second (new) select.

Comment: thanks for the answers....this code can't create a new select box with same value...if i click add button,,first select box was disappear....